# what is the better way to create a lifecycle index managed by app not Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch 7.15 and Kibana for searching text. The way I am creating index is daily index. Every time my application tries to save data to Elasticsearch, it will creates an index with date as the suffix: `logs-2022-01-10`.

I need to create an index lifecycle to delete the index which is older than 30 days. I have come cross some tutorial like: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html but it is all about creating an index template and let Elasticsearch to create the index when certain threshold is hit.

Is there a simple way to create a delete policy based on the index name pattern without creating index template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Apply Lifecycle Policy Manually](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html#apply-policy-manually) which you can use to assign ILM policy directly to index without template. Below is sample configuration you can set to index for apply policy manually.

```
PUT test-index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy" 
  }
}
```

To create a lifecycle policy from Kibana, open the menu and go to **Stack Management** > **Index Lifecycle Policies**. Click **Create policy**.

Click on the tiny delete icon to enable Delete Phase.

[image]

Comment: thanks, is there a way to filter index by name when create the policy in Kibana? If I chose 30 days, will it delete all index older than 30 days? can I only delete `log-*` index?

Comment: For thsi you need to create index template where you will give the alias name or pattern name. Also, This will delete only index where you have define the index policy. let consider your application is creating index every day and while creating index you are assigning policy name but you have skip for Janyuary month index then it will not delete data from Janyuary index.

Comment: Do I need to create index template if I update every new index I created to use `"index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy" `?

Comment: No. you can pass this setting while creating index from your application. If you are using Java Highlevel client then `request.settings(Settings.builder() 
    .put("index.number_of_shards", 3)
    .put("index.number_of_replicas", 2).put("index.lifecycle.name", "my_policy")
);`

Answer (score -2):

the only way to do this would be to use Elasticsearch Curator, which is an older generation tool, or to DIY

Comment: please check my answer. there is way you can do without Index Teamplate and you can applied manul life cycle policy while creating index.